# New google account and Gmail API

Tags: java, gmail-api

I just created a new google account to use Gmail API. When selecting MAIL_GOOGLE_COM scope it gives me this error.

```
GET https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages
{
  "code": 403,
  "details": [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
      "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
    }
  ],
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Insufficient Permission",
      "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

This did not happen when I used my other Google account which is my main account. Might the problem be that my account is new and is restricted somehow?

Edit:

```
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);
```

Comment: What is `MAIL_GOOGLE_COM` scope. Google API scopes generally looks like https url. These are Gmail scopes that I can see https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes

Comment: Figured it out, I had to delete old tokens file to change the scope :D